# How do I install LibreOffice?

Tags: raspbian, packages

When I type

```
$ sudo apt-get install libreoffice<tab>
```

I see there are 141 tab completions. All the language packs are there as well as several support packages.

But [`libreoffice`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibreOffice) itself is absent.

Recently the LibreOffice package has been added to the Debian 7 (Wheezy) repository.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? It runs slow on my Atom PC.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain, Well I am not planning to use it every day. Just thought it would be handy to be able to edit a file occasionally

Comment: http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/armhf/libreoffice/download Seems to be there. Sounds odd that there would be a build problem that would make just that disappear from raspbian.

Comment: It sounds like a Raspbian bug.

Comment: Depending on your requirements for "editing a file" there might be better options.  If you just need text files then gedit would be fine.  If you need more rich document editing capabilities, then Abiword might be worth looking into. I haven't used it much myself, but it doesn support the OpenOffice document format.

Comment: The distribution http://www.bodhilinux.com/ (Ubuntu derivat) seem to support libreoffice at least someone reported it to work with it. I dunno why libreoffice is not available, maybe it's too much too build (biggest package I know of)

Answer (score 7):

On Debian Wheezy, [`libreoffice`](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libreoffice) is a meta-package, which installs the following packages:

- `libreoffice-writer`: Word processor
- `libreoffice-calc`: Spreadsheet
- `libreoffice-impress`: Presentation
- `libreoffice-draw`: Drawing
- `libreoffice-base`: Database
- `libreoffice-math`: Equation editor
- `libreoffice-filter-mobiledev`: Mobile Devices filters

Therefore, you can install the equivalent by running

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-writer libreoffice-calc libreoffice-impress libreoffice-draw libreoffice-base libreoffice-math libreoffice-filter-mobiledev
```

Comment: Aha. I had to `apt-get update` even to install `libreoffice-writer` and noticed that `libreoffice` is also installable now.